# Date-picker using select statement oracle

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement date-picker functionality in my project, but I can't do it quite right. I'm trying to pass the date-picker value in my oracle string so that it will compare with my db column and return results on the date criteria...

Whenever I pass it to the select statement it won't generate errors particularly but on button click it doesn't perform anything except it shows "not connected".

```
 str = "Select * from sania.doctor where APPOINTMENT_DATE = "+ datepicker1.value;
```

It is clear it is logical mistake but I'm new to this C# concepts I need someone to tell me how to pass it and then display the results as well.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    try
        {
            OracleCommand com;
            OracleDataAdapter oda;
            string ConString = "Data Source=XE;User Id=system;Password=sania;";
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString);
            {
               // string id = dateTimePicker1.Text.Trim();
                con.Open();
               // str = "Select * from sania.doctor where APPOINTMENT_DATE = " + dateTimePicker1.value;
                str = "select * from sania.doctor where APPOINTMENT_DATE to_date('"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "', 'yyyymmdd')";
                com = new OracleCommand(str);
                oda = new OracleDataAdapter(com.CommandText, con);
                dt = new DataTable();
                oda.Fill(dt);
                Rowcount = dt.Rows.Count;
                //int val = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Rowcount; i++)
                {
                     dt.Rows[i]["APPOINTMENT_DATE"].ToString();

//if (id == dateTimePicker1.Value)// this LINE SHOWS ERROR--because it is a string and I am using date with it. Don't know conversion
                   // {
                       // val = 1;
                    //}
                }
               // if (val == 0)
               // { MessageBox.Show("INVALID ID"); }
               // else
               // {

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    oda.Fill(ds);
                    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {

                        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                    }

                   else { MessageBox.Show("NO RECORDS FOUND"); }
                     }
            }

        //}
        catch (Exception)
        { MessageBox.Show("not connected"); }
     }
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete button click code?

Comment: Try `str  = "Select * from sania.doctor where APPOINTMENT_DATE = '"+ datepicker1.value + "'";`

Comment: What error? can you post your error message?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Rowcount; i++)
                    {
                        id = dt.Rows[i]["APPOINTMENT_DATE"].ToString();
  if (id == dateTimePicker1.Value)// this LINE SHOWS ERROR--bcuz its string and i am using date with it dnt know conversion
                        {
                            val = 1;
                        }

Answer (score 2):

Do *not* put values into SQL *directly*, use bind ***variables/parametes*** instead. For Oracle:

```
// :prm_Appointment_Date bind variable declared within the query
String str = 
  @"select *
      from sania.doctor
     where Appointment_Date = :prm_Appointment_Date"; 

....

using(OracleCommand q = new OracleCommand(MyConnection)) {
  q.CommandText = str;

  // datepicker1.Value passed into :prm_Appointment_Date via parameter
  q.Parameters.Add(":prm_Appointment_Date", datepicker1.Value);
  ...
}
```

Doing like that you can be safe from either *SQL Injection* or *Format/Culture differences*